# Magento 2 : Get simple products from configurable (with Out of stock products)

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

I'm looking for get the simple products associated to a configurable one. I'm currently using this :
`$product->getTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);`
Where **$product** is a configurable.

But it return me simple products that have **quantity > 0**. Is there a method to  also get the 'out of stock' products from a configurable ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following class is configurable product type class:

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php

Check the following method for child product collection:

```
public function getUsedProductCollection($product)
```

Comment: Could you please help on this issue Please 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293795/rolled-back-transaction-has-not-been-completed-correctly-while-saving-product

Comment: It only returns products with In-Stock status.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done :

`$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductCollection($product)->getData()`

Thank you Sohel Rana !

Answer (score 1):

actually the getUsedProducts method only returns the in-stock products.
To solve this problem I did the following:

```
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable;

private Configurable $configurable;

public function __construct(Configurable $configurable) 
{
    $this->configurable = $configurable
}

public function getAllChildren($productId)
{
   $this->configurable->getChildrenIds($productId);
}
```

This will return all product ids, including those without stock.

The downside is that just seeing the ID it will be necessary to consult the Repository to get the product data,